MiniClusterWithClientResource unable to locate dynamically generated code
I have a project which exposes a GUI to client where client can use drag and drop functionality and can configure Flink source and sink. GUI component supports multiple types of source and sink like Kafka,File,DB etc and multiple types for serializer/deserializer too. We have some pre-defined map functions on GUI where a user can provide JSON schema of the object. At back-end, we compose java code based on GUI configuration, convert it into JAR and render it to Flink.
This is running fine on a Unix machine. But while writing Integration Tests using MiniClusterWithClientResource, I am facing issue related to the java code generated dynamically based on GUI configuration.
I tried registering my classes as well as jar using URLClassLoader
    URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new File(jarName).toURI().toURL() });
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);

I have also registered the path of dynamically generated jars in pom under maven-surefire-plugin configuration
<additionalClasspathElements
    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.directory}</additionalClasspathElement>
</additionalClasspathElements>

But still MiniClusterWithClientResource classloader unable to locate my dynamically generated classes/jar.
NOTE: This solution works for Windows but not in CI machine in Unix.
I get exception shown below:
 org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2075)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:268)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2075)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2075)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:621)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
 Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobInitializationException: Could not start the JobMaster.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultJobMasterServiceProcess.lambda$new$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceProcess.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Cannot instantiate the coordinator for operator Source: Kafka_Collector -> Filter -> Kafka_Distributor: Writer -> Kafka_Distributor: Committer
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    ... 3 more
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Cannot instantiate the coordinator for operator Source: Kafka_Collector -> Filter -> Kafka_Distributor: Writer -> Kafka_Distributor: Committer
    at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:321)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:114)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 3 more
 Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Cannot instantiate the coordinator for operator Source: Kafka_Collector -> Filter -> Kafka_Distributor: Writer -> Kafka_Distributor: Committer
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.initialize(ExecutionJobVertex.java:229)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.initializeJobVertex(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:901)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.initializeJobVertices(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.attachJobGraph(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:848)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.attachJobGraph(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:830)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.java:203)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:156)
 [mini-cluster-io-thread-2] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher - Job 155cebff305d242ab4b9750b0730f0a4 has been registered for cleanup in the JobResultStore after reaching a terminal state.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:361)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.<init>(SchedulerBase.java:206)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.<init>(DefaultScheduler.java:134)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:369)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:346)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112)
    ... 4 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Employee.AverageAge
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$SafetyNetWrapperClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:192)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1892)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1680)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2518)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2412)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2250)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1709)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2518)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2412)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2250)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1709)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2518)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2412)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2250)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1709)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2518)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2412)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2250)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1709)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:458)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:617)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:602)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.util.SerializedValue.deserializeValue(SerializedValue.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder.create(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:488)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.createOperatorCoordinatorHolder(ExecutionJobVertex.java:286)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.initialize(ExecutionJobVertex.java:223)
    ... 20 more

